# when a folder has no files in it, the date value is shown as "1900-01-01". I want the value to be today's date if there are no files in it

Tags: excel, vba

The below code helps in finding the newest file date in a folder, but when a folder has no files in it, then the date value is shown as "1900-01-01". Instead I want the value to be today's date if there are no files in it.

```
Sub oldestdate()

Range("G10").Value = GetOldestFile("C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\My files")

End Sub


Public Function GetOldestFile(ByVal FileFolder As String, _
                              Optional ByVal FileMask As String = "*.*", _
                              Optional ByVal FullName As Boolean = True) As String

   Dim FoundFile        As String
   Dim FileDT           As Date

   Dim NewestFile       As String
   Dim NewestDT         As Date

   Dim FS As Object

   '// Get rid of any terminating '\' just to get to a known state
   If Right(Trim(FileFolder), 1) = "\" Then
      FileFolder = Left(FileFolder, Len(Trim(FileFolder)) - 1)
   End If

   '// Get First file found in described folder
   FoundFile = Dir$(FileFolder & "\" & FileMask)

   '// Default return date
   NewestDT = DateValue("1900-01-01")

   Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   '// Loop through the rest of the files in that folder
   Do Until FoundFile = ""

      FileDT = FS.GetFile(FileFolder & "\" & FoundFile).DateCreated

      '// Compare Current File datetime with oldest found
      If FileDT > NewestDT Then
         NewestFile = FoundFile
         NewestDT = FileDT
      End If

      '// Get next file
      FoundFile = Dir$
   Loop

   Set FS = Nothing

   GetOldestFile = Format(NewestDT, "mm/dd/yyyy")

End Function
```

> Please let me know how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the loop insert this code line.

```
if NewestDT = DateValue("1900-01-01") then NewestDT = Date
```